# FBDialog.bundle no such file or directory (ShareKit 2.0)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I'm using *Sharekit 2.0* in my app but when I build app this error cames. I'm not getting what they are saying I tried my best to solve this from different questions but was not able.

> *error: /Users/shaheen.r/Downloads/ShareKit-ShareKit-bd8932b 3/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/../../../../../Submodules/facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBDialog.bundle:
>   No such file or directory*

The old version of *Sharekit* is also producing error and not working. How to solve this problem?

Comment: is the file FBDialog.bundle exists in the folder of your application?

Comment: if you dont find the file in the application import the file by downloading here. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/fdcf49627c9cd040e64472aff284bf3b061fb5e1/src

Comment: when i download then there is no file in Facebook all the files with in the Facebook api are looking Red, i also tried to add a submodule from the [link](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) but when i add this then it produce other error like "Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
" what can i do to solve this?

Comment: i have copied from that link and then delete Facebook file from the Sharekit in my App and drag and drop the downloaded file from the above link but then it create Other error "Clang failed with exit code 1"

Comment: Go to target -> build phases->compile sources and remove the red color files. make sure the facebook class files are present in the compiler sources

Comment: Thanks "Sumanth" for helping me but there is no red files in compile sources, i downloaded the facebook sdk and then add to sharekit but when i add this another error came "SSkeychain.h not found" after adding SSKeyChain it give another error Clang failed with exit code 1(jsonKit.h)not found, what the hell is this Sharekit 2.0?

Comment: @ Shaheen Rehman ok i understand your problem i have a share kit sample code working with out errors in xcode 4.3.3 with ios 5.1. If you need you can download from here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2y3lg79fjoihsrq/ShareKit.zip
If you get any doubt ask me again

Answer (score 0):

@ Shaheen Rehman ok i understand your problem i have a share kit sample code working with out errors in xcode 4.3.3 with ios 5.1. If you need you can download from [here](http://dropbox.com/s/2y3lg79fjoihsrq/ShareKit.zip).  If you get any doubt ask me again

Comment: @ Sumanth thanks for your help, i have done it the main problem was that that i downloaded the sharekit direct from Zip file. Now i have downloaded it through Git it is working. thanks for your help

Comment: there is no SDK in the above link "No Data Found" it give me a message

Comment: okay i have uploaded sharekit again and check this link now https://www.dropbox.com/s/2y3lg79fjoihsrq/ShareKit.zip

Comment: The link you provided is not working can you please create another one?